# Cannot set parent().css() for select2-container in document ready jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have input field select2 bootstrap

```
<select id="selectValue" class="selectValue form-control select2" name="selectValue" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Value</option>
  <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option> 
  <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option> 
</select>
```

My goal is, when page first loaded , I want jQuery to set border to red color for select2-selectValue-container.

But it's not working. It's only working when I clicked/change dropdown. Am I missing something here ?

Full code as below.

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

    /* This is not working */
    $('#select2-selectValue-container').parent().css({'border' : 'solid 1px red'});
    
    /* This one working fine */
    $(".selectValue").change(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var selected = $(this).val();
      if(selected === "" || selected === undefined || selected === null){
        $('#select2-selectValue-container').parent().css('border', 'solid 1px red');
      } else {
        $('#select2-selectValue-container').parent().css('border', 'solid 1px green'); 
      }  
    });

  });
</script>
```

Appreciate if someone can help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: try to add `.change()` at the end .. `$(".selectValue").change(function(e){ ..... }).change();`

Comment: problem is in line number 6 .

Comment: Hi @RzjHayabusa , It's working for me . Please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7dra15bn/).